# Tax forms required for heirs who receive money from sale of an estate?

Tags: united-states, taxes, inheritance, death

The probated estate is small; no state or federal taxes will be owed for the estate or for those who inherit. The property will be sold and money distributed to the heirs.

Are federal 1099s still required for each person who inherits?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer is no for 1099s but yes for K-1. Here is an extract from IRS publication 559 for Survivors, Executors, and Administrators:

*The personal representative must file a separate
Schedule K-1 (Form 1041), Beneficiary's
Share of Income, Deductions, Credits, etc. or
an acceptable substitute (described below), for
each beneficiary. File these schedules with
Form 1041.
The personal representative must ask each
beneficiary to provide a taxpayer identification
number (TIN), which must be reported on the
Schedule K-1 (Form 1041). A $50 penalty is
charged for each failure to provide the identifying
number of each beneficiary unless reasonable
cause is established. A nonresident alien
beneficiary with a withholding certificate generally
must provide a TIN (see Pub. 515). A TIN
isn't required for an executor or administrator of
the estate unless that person is also a beneficiary.*

For the full 40+ page publication, see 
https://www.irs.gov/pub/irs-pdf/p559.pdf